# document.getElementById(control).value not working with IE8

Tags: html

```
var tagID = document.getElementByn("<%=ddlSectionHeaderID%>").value;
var tagIndex = document.getElementById("<%=ddlSectionHeaderID%>").selectedIndex;
var tagName = document.getElementById("<%=ddlSectionHeaderID%>").children(tagIndex).innerText;
var exportID = document.getElementById("<%=hdnExportID%>").value;
```

This gives me "Object doesn't support this property"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to see the rendered output and what references resulted in the rendered script.

The "Object doesn't support this property" error means that you are trying to access a property that does not exist for that object.  perhaps when this script is rendered, what you think should be a select element is actually a text input.  If that is the case, the selectedIndex property wont exist (this is just one possibility - you will know more if you were able to see the resulting string).

Comment: it is typo only while asking question. Code have getElementById

Comment: Just for your knowledge, it works fine for IE6, IE7 and compatibility view of IE8

Comment: I see that you accepted my answer, but I cannot tell whether you were able to fix your issue.  Can you provide some details?